# Lower Bound for the square root of the sum of squares

Tags: radicals, upper-lower-bounds, square-numbers

I am looking for a good lower bound for the square root of the sum of squares:

Let's say we have some known parameters : $x_i > 0$ where i $\in [1,...,n]$

I am looking for a good lower bound of this term (a sum or something similar but not a *one square root term*):

$\sqrt{\sum_{i}x_i^2}$

PS: $\min{x_i}$ is a lower bound but not of a good quality.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe one of these will help? https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bound $\sqrt{n} \min x_i$ is better than $\min x_i$, and is sharp, in the sense that it becomes an equality, in case the $x_i$ are all equal.

EDIT: Sorry - I just saw the comment on your answer. The one in the link is better than mine, in that it is generally greater than the one I gave.

SECOND EDIT: That is, $(\sum x_i)/\sqrt{n}$.