# Lower bound for the square root of the sum of variables including squares

Tags: integers, upper-lower-bounds, sums-of-squares, sum-of-squares-method

I already got a nice answer for a similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3734505) while now i am looking for a lower bound for the square root of the sum of variables including squares and binary decision variables to address a MILP with CPLEX:

Let's say we have some known parameters : $x_i > 0$ where
and a set of binary decision variables $y_i \in \{0,1\}$ where i $\in [1,...,n]$

I am looking for a good lower bound of this term (a sum or something similar but not a *one square root term*):

**$\sqrt{\sum_{i}y_ix_i^2}$**

The constraint is written as follows by the way : $a - b \le z\sqrt{\sum_{i}y_ix_i^2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive decision variables and $z$ is a parameter ($z < 0$).

PS: $\min{x_i}$ is a lower bound but not of a good quality.

Comment: Do you mean $0\le y_1\le 1$ or "$y_i$ is either $0$ or $1$" by $y_i \in [0,1]$? In either case, setting all $y_i$ to $0$ yields $0$.

Comment: it is either 0 or 1, i'm correcting this typo now

Comment: So all $y_i$ can't be $0$ simultaneously? Or if they can, we have only $0$ the lower bound.

Comment: Yes, all $y_i$ can be equal to 0 simultaneously but i have a binary decision variable which is equal to 0 if all $y_i$ are equal to 0. The lower bound i am looking for is when one or more $y_i$ are equal to one and this why i indicated that $min x_i$ is already a LB i know.

Comment: So it's the best lower bound IMHO once it's reached. What makes this bound no good (of poor quality)?

Comment: It is a bad quality in the case of more than $y_i$ are equal to one. For example, if 5 $y_i$ are equal to one then the lower bound is very far from the real value of the term.