# lower bound on the squared sum of random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, concentration-of-measure

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be $n$ iid random variables such that each $X_i$ follows from the continuous uniform distribution in $[-1,1]$.

I am looking for a lower bound on
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right].
$$

Note that by using Jensen's inequality, we can provide an upperbound:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right] \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[X_i^2\right]} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{3}},
$$
where the last step follows from simple calculation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734476/lower-bound-for-the-square-root-of-the-sum-of-squares this might be helpful

Comment: Thanks. I posted an answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: One can use a mean-concentration inequality, such as Chebychev. Letting $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$, and $\mu, \sigma$ be the mean and standard deviation of $Y$, we have from Chebychev, \begin{align*}
E(\sqrt{Y}) &= E(\sqrt{Y} \big| |Y-\mu| \geq k \sigma) P(|Y-\mu| \geq k \sigma) + E(\sqrt{Y} \big| |Y-\mu| < k \sigma) P(|Y-\mu| < k \sigma) \\
&\geq E(\sqrt{Y} | |Y-\mu| < k \sigma) (1 - 1/k^2) \\
&\geq \sqrt{\mu - k\sigma} (1-1/k^2)
\end{align*}

and then you can fill in $\mu, \sigma$ and then choose $k$ to maximize the lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @VazenBu comment, we can provide the following lowerbound.

Let $z_1,\dots, z_n$ be $n$ numbers such that $z_i \in [0,1]$. Then, we can show that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_i}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_i}.
$$

We can use the above inequality to argue that

$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\right]}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right].
$$
Note that $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i^2\right]=\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore, we have
$$
 \frac{\sqrt{n}}{3} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right].
$$